# Problema con Try-Catch

Tags: c#, .net

Me dice "uso de la variable local no asignada "fecha" y no me deja compilar siquiera.

¿A caso no debería si o si entrar al Try y en tiempo de ejecución tal vez darme error?

```
DateTime fecha;

        try
        {
            Console.Write("Fecha de nacimiento: ");
            nacimiento = Console.ReadLine();
            fecha = Convert.ToDateTime(nacimiento);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Error: El formato debe ser en dd/mm/aa");

        }

        Console.WriteLine(fecha);
```

Comment: Hola.la variable `fecha` debes inicializar la primero digamos a `DateTime.Now`  o declararla como `Nullabe` y asignarle `null`. Así: `DateTime? fecha = null;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Respuesta corta: está fuera de ámbito (scope)

Esto funciona:

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("¡Saludos Hermandad de SOes!");

        DateTime fecha;

        try
        {
            Console.Write("Fecha de nacimiento: ");
            var nacimiento = Console.ReadLine();
            fecha = Convert.ToDateTime(nacimiento);
            Console.WriteLine(fecha);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: El formato debe ser en dd/mm/aa");
        }       
    }
}
```

Esto también funciona:

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("¡Saludos Hermandad de SOes!");

        DateTime? fecha = null;

        try
        {
            Console.Write("Fecha de nacimiento: ");
            var nacimiento = Console.ReadLine();
            fecha = Convert.ToDateTime(nacimiento);

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: El formato debe ser en dd/mm/aa");
        }       
        Console.WriteLine(fecha);
    }
}
```

La razón del por qué esto funciona es la declaración "null" de la "fecha", logramos esto gracias al caracter "?".

Puedes definirlo de la siguiente manera también:

```
Nullable<DateTime> fecha = null;
```

Te recomiendo leer sobre tipos nulos: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/nullable-types/

Answer (score 1):

Al momento de hacer `DateTime fecha;` no haces mas que reservar un objeto de tipo DateTime, sin embargo esto no significa hacer un objeto `DateTime`, para esto tienes que inicializarla ( `DateTime fecha = new DateTime();` ) o hacerla null ( 
`DateTime fecha = null;` ).
El mensaje de error pasa porque en caso de que el `try` falle, en ningún momento logra inicializar la variable.

Answer (score 0):

El mensaje de error :

> "uso de la variable local no asignada "fecha"

es debido a que tienes que inicializar la variable `fecha`, debes inicializarla:

```
  DateTime fecha = DateTime.MinValue;
```

---

Este sería el código completo:

```
DateTime fecha = DateTime.MinValue;

    try
    {
        Console.Write("Fecha de nacimiento: ");
        nacimiento = Console.ReadLine();
        fecha = Convert.ToDateTime(nacimiento);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

        Console.WriteLine("Error: El formato debe ser en dd/mm/aa");

    }

    Console.WriteLine(fecha);
```